# How to I restore my file association so that .jar files are opened with java instead of unarchiver (on Mac)?

Tags: java, jar

I have the latest versions of both JDK and JRE installed on my Mac.

I downloaded unarchiver recently, and accidentally changed the default program to open .jar files to it, so now when I double-click on a .jar file it automatically opens in unarchiver.

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find any useful information on a simple way to just change the file association back. Java doesn't show up as an 'application,' so I can't just click on select a different application and chose Java as the application to open the .jar with.

Please help